# Unwanted Google Keep reminders when Google Keep is not installed

Tags: google-keep

I use two Android devices regularly.  A Nexus 5 which is my daily driver, calendars, Google Keep, etc.  The second device is an Asus Tablet which I use to consume - newspapers, news, magazines, internet, etc.  I try to minimize all the alerts on this tablet since I don't need any notifications from my calendar or other daily apps.

I am a heavy user of Google Keep on my Nexus 5 but have not installed it on my tablet (on purpose).  And yet, each time I set a reminder that I want to see on my phone, I also get a notification on my Tablet of the form (e.g.) "Pick Up Eggs - Install Google Keep".  It also uses the Google Now reminder icon (finger with a bowtie) and not the Google Keep icon (lightbulb).  I should also mention that I do not have Google Now enabled on any of my devices.

I do not want Google Keep nor the reminders on my Tablet.  I've tried removing various sync services under the Google Account but can't seem to find the one that is synchronizing the Google Keep reminders to my Tablet.

Any suggestions as to how to get rid of these useless notifications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.

Can you see Keep under `Settings > Accounts > Google > <<Your google account address>> > Sync Keep` on your tablet?

Edit: I just realized that you do not have Keep installed on the tablet...

Well, maybe a stupid patch could be to install it on the tablet too, and then disable synchronizing?

Comment: To answer anyways... no I can't see Google Keep under the account.  Installing and disabling sync is worth a try though.

Comment: Doncho, I installed Keep and then disabled sync and it had the required effect.  Notifications disappeared.  I'll accept the second half of your answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. When the notification appears pull down the notification bar. From there hold down on the Google Keep notification. A little pop up with 'App Info' will appear. Click on it. That will show you what app is causing the pop up. From there you can either disable the entire app or disable notification. For this insurance it looks like it is Google Play Services that is the culprit. I choose to disable the notifications only.

Comment: Won't this supress a number of other important messages?  It's a common framework for a number of things.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is install google keep again and go to trash there you will find the note with the reminder ,then delete the reminder and delete forever and that got rid of my reminders